How to conditionally postpone or defer a DAG run in apache Airflow
In Apache Airflow, I have dag that triggers manually by external organizations via rest API. Is there any standard mechanism to postpone or defer a DAG run based on certain conditions, such as checking if another run for a particular organization is still running.
Some thing like this:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
}


def main_task(**kwargs):
   if organization_has_running_dag() :
      postpone_dag(minutes=10)
   do_main_job() 


dag = DAG(
    'example_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='An example DAG to postpone runs',
)

main_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='main_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=check_org_run,
    dag=dag,
)

main_task


I have thought about using sleep.wait() in a while loop:
def main_task(**kwargs):
   while organization_has_running_dag() :
      time.sleep(5*60)
   do_main_job()

However I am looking for more standard approach, a standard way to rescheduling the dag, and not waiting in task until other runs finish.

You can use a Custom Sensor to implement your condition before running the main_task.

@vdolez can you please make example with your solution as answer?

for this you need to detail your Use Case with the condition you want :)

@vdolez, I checked the solution, it's something like my own solution mentioned at end of question. I am looking for a standard way to rescheduling the dag., and not waiting in tasks until other run finish.

There's a contraction in your question. If you explicitly tell Airflow to execute a DAG run (as you do by calling the rest API) then why would you want it to not be executed ? You should consider to delegate this behavior to the caller, or use another tool to handle this use case. Especially if you want to do this because of concurrency reasons because Airflow is NOT made to handle events.
